# create concentric rings around a point with sf

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I am trying to create concentric rings around a point with sf. In searching it seems that a solution is to 
create 2 buffers and then use st_difference them like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
point <- c(0,0)
point <- st_point(point)

buff1 <- st_buffer(point, dist=1)
buff2 <- st_buffer(point, dist=2)
ring <- st_difference(buff2, buff1)

ring %>%
ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

Is there a better (faster) approach. The application that I am using requires this to be done for 100 rings around 200 points and is very slow. Any ideas? I tried playing with the CIRCULARSTRING geometries but couldn't figure out how that works.

Comment: Something different from a loop, apply or map approach?

Comment: yeah, that's what I am basically doing now, creating the 2 buffers then subtracting with st_difference all inside an apply

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but what about replicating the points and creating an array of distances for the rings to be used in `st_buffer` ? Something like this could work:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

pts = st_sfc(st_point(1:2), st_point(3:4), st_point(8:9))
pts = st_sf(a=1:3, geometry = pts)

# replicate your points N times (N = number of rings)
N = 20
pts_rep <- pts
for (n in 2:N) pts_rep <- rbind(pts_rep,pts)

# create a array of buffer distances and replicate it N times
dists <- seq(1, 4, 0.05)
dists <- rep(dists, N)

# apply buffer
buff1 <- st_buffer(pts_rep, dists) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(., "LINESTRING"): repeating attributes for all sub-
#> geometries for which they may not be constant

buff1 %>%
ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

HTH!